# Sympy: Is there a way to collect and factorise the constant terms

Tags: python, sympy

If I have this expression:

*x<sup>2</sup>a<sub>2</sub> - x<sup>2</sup>b<sub>2</sub> + 2xa<sub>1</sub> - 2xb<sub>1</sub> + 12a<sub>0</sub> - 12b<sub>0</sub>*

How do I get sympy to give me this?

*x<sup>2</sup>(a<sub>2</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>) + 2x(a<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>1</sub>) + 12(a<sub>0</sub> - b<sub>0</sub>)*

This is my code:

```
from sympy import sympify, factor_terms, collect
x = symbols('x', real=True)
a2, a1, a0  = symbols('a2 a1 a0', real = True, constant = True)
b2, b1, b0  = symbols('b2 b1 b0', real = True, constant = True)
c2, c1, c0  = symbols('c2 c1 c0', real = True, constant = True)

expr = sympify(x**2*a2 - x**2*b2 + 2*a1*x - 2*b1*x + 12*a0 - 12*b0)
f_expr = factor_terms(collect(expr, x))
display(f_expr)
```

Returns:

*x<sup>2</sup>(a<sub>2</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>) + 2x(a<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>1</sub>) + 12a<sub>0</sub> - 12b<sub>0</sub>*

What I'm looking for is something that collects the constant terms (coefficients of *x<sup>0</sup>* and is able to factorize them. Namely

*x<sup>2</sup>(a<sub>2</sub> - b<sub>2</sub>) + 2x(a<sub>1</sub> - b<sub>1</sub>) + 12(a<sub>0</sub> - b<sub>0</sub>)*

Mainly so that I can replace the differences with another variable.

```
f_expr.replace(a2 - b2, c2).replace(a1 - b1, c1).replace(a0 - b0, c0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do some expression wrangling to get this to happen. But doing an algebraic substitution is easier. Instead of replacing `a - b -> A` do `a -> b + A`:

```
>>> from sympy import var
>>> var('x:6')
(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
>>> eq = 2*x0-2*x1+3*x2-3*x3+4*x4-4*x5
>>> eq
2*x0 - 2*x1 + 3*x2 - 3*x3 + 4*x4 - 4*x5
>>> eq.subs(dict(x0=x1+x,x2=x3+y,x4=x5+z))
2*x + 3*y + 4*z
```